# Uploading csv file by ftp using Python

Tags: python, ftp

I've searched how to upload a csv file by ftp using Python. I tried this code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP("host")
ftp.login("user","password")
Output_Directory = "//ftp//data//"
File2Send="C://Test//test.csv"
file = open(File2Send, "rb")
ftp.cwd(Output_Directory)
 ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + File2Send, file)
```

[and that's what I got as an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwK92.png). I think I couldn't write ftp.storbinary function correctly. 
Can anyone tell me how to make it correct please?

Thank you

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of the error, copy/paste them in code format into your question. Links to images can expire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't double forward slashes `//`. The practice is to double backslashes `\\` because they are special escape characters. But forward slashes are normal.

Also when using the ftp `STOR` command you are already at the destination directory so you must send only the filename you want, not the full local path like you're doing.

```
Output_Directory = "/ftp/data/"
File2Send="C:/Test/test.csv"
ftp.cwd(Output_Directory)
with open(File2Send, "rb") as f:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + os.path.basename(File2Send), f)
```